# Regex and VB.net pattern matching

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am writing a VB.net program to detect a words. Here is my sample text file:

```
EXTERNAL 16EVP_PK   -- FL(4) TDC PERMIT CONTRL TO MESTO CONTRL  
                    -- FL(5) $HY04B09.BOXTSTAT (= RUN = ON)   
EXTERNAL 16EVPUPK   -- FL(33) REQUEST FROM METSO FOR CONTRL   
EXTERNAL 16SA0541                                 -- SP VALUES TRANSFERS  
EXTERNAL 16FC0730, 16FC0815, 16FC0830   -- Hiway 4 Tags   
EXTERNAL 16FC1525                       -- Hiway 4 Tags
```

I want to detect everything **after EXTERNAL and before --** (EXTERNAL can be external or ExTernal or any combination) . The first match should read "16EVP_PK" second match 16EVPUPK third match 16SA0541 fourth match "16FC0730, 16FC0815, 16FC0830" and so on

Here is the code that I have written:

```
Private Sub CheckCLFile()
path="D:\16METEVP.CL"
'Read CL file
Dim value As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
Dim Pattern As String = "(?m)(?<=\bExternal).*$"
Debug.WriteLine(value)
Debug.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(value, Pattern).Count())
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(value, Pattern)
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.",
                          m.Value, m.Index)
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`(?<=EXTERNAL)\s*.*?(?=\s*--)`

With this you will get extra leading spaces before each match. I guess, you can easily trim that before using the matches.

[Click for Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dEXTERNAL%29%5cs*.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cs*--%29&i=EXTERNAL+16EVP_PK+--+FL%284%29+TDC+PERMIT+CONTRL+TO+MESTO+CONTRL+--+FL%285%29+%24HY04B09.BOXTSTAT+%28%3d+RUN+%3d+ON%29+EXTERNAL+16EVPUPK+--+FL%2833%29+REQUEST+FROM+METSO+FOR+CONTRL+EXTERNAL+16SA0541+--+SP+VALUES+TRANSFERS+EXTERNAL+16FC0730%2c+16FC0815%2c+16FC0830+--+Hiway+4+Tags+EXTERNAL+16FC1525+--+Hiway+4+Tags&o=i)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=EXTERNAL)` - Positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by `EXTERNAL`. Switch the `Ignore Case` flag ON.
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of white-spaces, as many as possible
- `.*?` - This is your actual match. It matches 0+ occurrences of any character but a new-line character, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*--)` - Positive lookahead to validate that the match must be followed by 0+ spaces followed by `--`

Comment: Gurman - very close, but where 3 tags (16FC0730, 16FC0815, 16FC0830 ) needs to be selected, I see only one (16FC0730). I need to select everything after External but before --. Thanks.

Comment: Hi...I hadn't read that properly..I have now updated the solution

Comment: Very nice explanation. Learned something new about Regex. Thanks Gurman.

Comment: Using .NET, thus no need for the lookbehind to be fixed length, no need to trim leading spaces if `\s*` goes into it.

Comment: @PJProudhon Thanks for that information. I didn't know about that. Here is the updated solution [`(?<=EXTERNAL\s+).*?(?=\s*--)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dEXTERNAL%5cs%2b%29.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cs*--%29&i=EXTERNAL+16EVP_PK+--+FL%284%29+TDC+PERMIT+CONTRL+TO+MESTO+CONTRL+--+FL%285%29+%24HY04B09.BOXTSTAT+%28%3d+RUN+%3d+ON%29+EXTERNAL+16EVPUPK+--+FL%2833%29+REQUEST+FROM+METSO+FOR+CONTRL+EXTERNAL+16SA0541+--+SP+VALUES+TRANSFERS+EXTERNAL+16FC0730%2c+16FC0815%2c+16FC0830+--+Hiway+4+Tags+EXTERNAL+16FC1525+--+Hiway+4+Tags&o=i)